# Bootstrap Grid thumbnails with expanded preview on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application, part of which is listing posts for a user profile:

```
<div class="row">
    <%@posts.each do |x|%>   
        <div class="col-lg-4">   
          <%=x.body%>
        </div>    
    <%end%> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid black">
        dsafasf
      </div>
    </div>
```

If i wasn't using dynamic data (lots of posts), this is what i want to happen ultimately (one row of posts shows up - then on click the large row underneath is toggled): 
https://jsfiddle.net/nk2vLhhp/2/

However, I am trouble having this work with dynamic data. It is currently just showing one large row at the end of all posts (not just one row of posts). I want one large col-12 row after every three posts

How would i go about doing this? Any help please?

PS: My end, end goal is something like this: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

Comment: there are many ways to do this. On the top of my head, you can simply insert the post-content below on click instead of creating a permanent row. https://jsfiddle.net/nk2vLhhp/8/

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it.

**Method 1 :**

```js
$('.col-xs-4').click(function() {
  $(".explanation").slideUp().remove();
  var $desc = $("<div/>", {
    class: 'explanation row'
  }); //it can contain a close button like the others.
  $desc.html($(this).find('.hidden').html());
  $(this).closest('.row').after($desc).slideDown();
});
```

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    post 1
    <div class='desc hidden'>Post 1 description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    post 2
    <div class='desc hidden'>Post 2 description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    post 3
    <div class='desc hidden'>Post 3 description</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    post 5
    <div class='desc hidden'>Post 5 description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    post 6
    <div class='desc hidden'>Post 6 description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    post 7
    <div class='desc hidden'>Post 7 description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2 (with animation) :**

Almost same as above but instead of creating the `div.explanation` everytime, simply define it hidden in the html, beneath every row.

https://jsfiddle.net/nk2vLhhp/13/

```js
$('.col-xs-4').click(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
  $('.explanation').hide();
  var targetClass = $target.attr('data-target');
  $('.' + targetClass).removeClass('hidden').hide().slideDown();
});
```

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4" data-target='1-content'>
    post 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" data-target='2-content'>
    post 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" data-target='3-content'>
    post 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-12 explanation hidden 1-content'>Post 1 description</div>
  <div class='col-xs-12 explanation hidden 2-content'>Post 2 description</div>
  <div class='col-xs-12 explanation hidden 3-content'>Post 3 description</div>
  <div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4" data-target='4-content'>
        post 4
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4" data-target='5-content'>
        post 5
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4" data-target='6-content'>
        post 6
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-12 explanation hidden 4-content'>Post 4 description</div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 explanation hidden 5-content'>Post 5 description</div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 explanation hidden 6-content'>Post 6 description</div>
      <div>
```

Comment: thanks, more specifically I am looking for something slightly more rails specific to help me make me get one col-xs-12 after every 3 posts that are displayed

Comment: sorry, I don't know rails, but a condition like `index%3===0` can help.